# Initialize C++ classes in a separate class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a QT application that has its functionality divided into independent modules, each with its own CPP and header files. All these classes are then initialized in `main.cpp`. However, doing this has the unfortunate side effect of increasing application boot times, possibly because everything is initialized simultaneously. To fix this, can I make another class with all these initialization statements from `main.cpp` moved to it so they are started only when required? Also, are there any other suggestions I can implement to help with the startup routine?

I'm pasting a snippet of code to show what statements I'm referring to that I plan on moving. Please do tell if there's any other information missing from the post that might be needed to give an answer.

```cpp
// INCLUDE STATEMENTS

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("QtApp");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // CAN THESE CLASS INITIALIZING STATEMENTS BE MOVED FROM MAIN.CPP TO A SEPARATE CLASS?

    // Create version class
    version *m_version = new version();
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("version", m_version);

    // Create gps class
    gps *m_gps = new gps(m_version, &app);
    m_gps->start();
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("gps", m_gps);

    // INITIALIZING OTHER CLASSES HERE

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The only thing I see that could be taking up time is if the creation of the GPS object must wait for it to get enough good signals from the satellites or not. Could this be postponed to later? Or perhaps run in the background (perhaps through a thread)?

Comment: That is kind of my idea for moving these initializations to a different class altogether, they would only be initialized once all the pre-requisites are fulfilled and they are actually required. However, I can't seem to get it to work that way so I wanted to see if this was a valid approach.

Comment: Moving code into a separate class doesn't make it automagically running parallel. Even if you move things into a class, you have to make an instance of this class to use it. So, there is still the same effort + the overhead of instancing the class. What you have to adjust is your control flow. One option is multi-threading but it comes with extra hurdles you have to care about. Another option is lazy evaluation -> initialize things when they are needed first. Sometimes this is helpful distributing one long delay into many small delays (which doesn't annoy the user anymore)...

Comment: ...but it can also result in moving a long delay to later without any advantage for the user appearance.

Comment: I still have another concern: What can you do with your application until the GPS is started? If the answer is "nothing" then... An application which appears up-and-running while it actually initializes in the background and the user cannot do anything with this isn't much added value (but the user might feel fooled). A simple alternative could be to distract the user somehow -> a splash screen can be used for this. (There is even a ready class for this in Qt: [QSplashScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html).) ;-)